# Cannot send request with yield all Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have two arrays : listingMapIds and selectedFeePayload. And what I wanted to do is for each listingMapId, send the amount of selectedFee, that is, if selectedFeePayload includes two objects then send two requests per listingMapId. Here is my code excerpt:

```
if (selectedFeePayload.length > 0) {
      const response = yield all(listingMapIds.map(listingMapId => selectedFeePayload.map(fee =>
        call(addListingOptionalFeeRequest, { listingMapId, payload: fee }))));

      console.log(response);
    }
```

but no request is sent pls help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `all` effect can handle nested array. Try flattening the array first.

```js
if (selectedFeePayload.length > 0) {
    const requests = listingMapIds.map(listingMapId => selectedFeePayload.map(fee =>
        call(addListingOptionalFeeRequest, { listingMapId, payload: fee })))
    const response = yield all(requests.flat());

    console.log(response);
}
```